# What's the meaning of matrix $A*\mathrm{orth}(A^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone give an explanation on the meaning of a matrix $A * \mathrm{orth}(A^{T})$, where $\textrm{orth}(A)$ is the matlab function, which compute the range of matrix $A$? $*$ is matrix multiplication. I am so confused by its function.

Actually, in practice, $A$ is a $D$-by-$N$ matrix, where each column is a $D$-dimensional data sample, and $N$ means there are $N$ data samples.

Thanks for your answer.

Reference

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orth.html

Answer (score 0):

$orth(A^T)$ will an orthonormal matrix. $A*orth(A^T)$ will be orthogonal, though not orthonormal.

I'm not sure from your question exactly what you are looking for, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I am looking for an explanation of this expression, an image of it, not only in pure math, but also in some particular meaning. For example, since each column of $A$ is a vector, representing a sample in reality, I'm wondering, after $A*orth(A^T)$, what's the meaning of its entry/row/column.